# How to check whether css get properly loaded or not in magento website

Tags: magento

I am trying to add some styling to a magento extension.For this I have tried to load  css file through its Extension.xml . by adding following code ->

```
<refernce name="head">
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>EXTENSION NAME/css/style.css</name><params/></action>

</refernce>
```

But it isn't working .
So my question is that how to check whether the css file is loaded or not in magento site.
I have tried checking the source file but does not contain  link to the css file that I want ,But it also does not contain the link to js file which is already present by default in Extension.xml.

Comment: Is the typo on `reference` also present in your layout, or is it due to the copy paste ?

Comment: Oh...didn't even see that one as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use firebug(if you are using mozilla firefox) to check your css , whether it is applied or not. And if the css is applied, it display the css name along side with its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell by looking at the page source to see if the lines of  and  codes are correctly being loaded...by the sounds of it in your case they are not.

My guess is your problem is either the closing params tag(why is that there?) or that the extension is not being loaded at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correctly initialized your extension and all files are placed in the right paths.

Asuming your namespace is "Yourcompany", your extension is called "Extension" and you are using the default/default theme, at the very least you need the following files:

1. app/etc/modules/Yourcompany_Extension.xml
2. app/code/local/Yourcompany/Extension/etc/config.xml
3. app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/extension.xml
4. skin/frontend/default/default/extension/css/style.css